# iPad HTML compatibility

Tags: html, ipad, compatibility

I've generated the HTML for a multiple choice question, simply using a single png that contains the question and multiple choice answers each containing a png of their own. I want the user to be able to click on the their answer of choice, and the move on to the next problem.

In testing, I've found that it works perfectly using standard browsers, but on an iPad I am unable to click the answer choices. I am not familiar with an iPad's html requirements/restrictions. I assume I'm doing something that apple's iPad version of safari doesn't support, though I don't know what it would be.

Here's the body:

```
<body onload="init('single')" class="single">
<div id="navBar">
  <div id="testButtons" class="formButtons"><button id="submitButton"><img src="../assets/check2.png">I'm done</button><button id="resetButton"><img src="../assets/delete2.png">Start over</button></div>
  <div id="resultsButtons" class="formButtons"></div>
</div>
<div id="test">
  <form>
    <div class="problem" id="problem-1">
      <div class="problemLabel"><span>Problem 1</span></div><img class="stem" src="1.png"><table class="answer">
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <th><input type="radio" name="rg-1" id="rb-1-1" class="false"><label for="rb-1-1">&#65;</label></th>
            <td><label for="rb-1-1"><img src="1-1.png"></label></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th><input type="radio" name="rg-1" id="rb-1-2" class="false"><label for="rb-1-2">&#66;</label></th>
            <td><label for="rb-1-2"><img src="1-2.png"></label></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th><input type="radio" name="rg-1" id="rb-1-3" class="true"><label for="rb-1-3">&#67;</label></th>
            <td><label for="rb-1-3"><img src="1-3.png"></label></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <th><input type="radio" name="rg-1" id="rb-1-4" class="false"><label for="rb-1-4">&#68;</label></th>
            <td><label for="rb-1-4"><img src="1-4.png"></label></td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
<div id="results">
  <h3 id="testcomplete">Online Test Complete!</h3>
  <div id="resultsHeader">
    <table class="summary">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <th>Title</th>
          <td>single_question_test</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>Correct</th>
          <td id="problemsCorrect"></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</body>
```

Any help would be much appreciated! Hoping it's something like a different button type should be used for iPads.

Answer (score 0):

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7780617/why-arent-my-website-radio-buttons-clickable-on-iphone-ipad):

If I had to guess, your table elements are covering your input elements on the iPad, which isn't allowing touch events. I would try making an HTML page with only radio buttons, making sure they're clickable, then working your way that way.